# How to execute a context menu command from PowerShell?

Tags: pdf, powershell, context-menu

I am trying to convert a file to pdf by calling the Shell.Application associated with the Context Menu (like when you right click on a file).

I borrowed and tweaked some code from another forum:

```
$o = new-object -com Shell.Application
$folder = $o.NameSpace("C:\Users\MyUserName\Downloads")
$file=$folder.ParseName("973.xfdl")
$file.Verbs() | %{ if($_.Name -eq 'Convert to Adobe PDF') { $_.DoIt() } }
```

It ran successfully exactly one time, then never again.  I cleared all the permissions issues associated with GPO and tested this by running a much simpler script (`remove-item "c:\users\MyUserName\downloads\Welcome to NFPA.htm"`) which worked perfectly.  I hope it is a simple format/syntax issue.  Does anyone know why this might be failing?

Thank you.  I also don't know how to make the darn thing have hard returns or whatever.  But, I goofed the first time, I forgot to put back my actual user name.

I forced it to run in PowerShellISE, it was trying to default to cmd even though I told it PowerShell.

Now that I have it correct, the error reads:

```
PDF Convert verb was not found for this file
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException
```

The program used by the context menu command is acrobat distiller.

I tried to look for the program or command that it actually runs, it wasn't where it was supposed to be in the registry, in fact, the actual test that appears in the context menu, 'Convert to Adobe PDF', is nowhere in the registry.

Dangph - thanks!  I actually reached the same solution at home last night.  I am good to go, thank you all!

Comment: which program you use to convert files?

Comment: So what happens when you try running this.  Do you get any errors?  You are using `$file.Verbs()`, are  you sure the verb is actually found, and still exists for that type of file?  Verbs like this are often simply calling other commands, perhaps instead of trying to get the verb from the shell, you should look up the command the shell actually runs, and just call that directly?

Comment: Acrobat Distiller has a command line interface. Can't you use that? See "Command line options" in the Acrobat Distiller API Reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command line tool like PDFcreator

```
pdfcreator.exe /PrintFile="C:\test.doc"
```

Comment: Thanks.  There a dozens of things like that which I could use, were I not on a government computer :( Thus my search for a scripting solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some error handling to your code, this may help you find the problem.

```
$o = new-object -com Shell.Application
$folder = $o.NameSpace("C:\Users\MyUserName\Downloads")
$file=$folder.ParseName("973.xfdl")
[array]$PdfConvertVerb = $file.Verbs() | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'Convert to Adobe PDF' }
If ($PdfConvertVerb -eq 1) {
    $PdfConvertVerb[0].DoIt()
} Else {
    Write-Error 'PDF Convert verb was not found for this file'
}
```

Comment: That was interesting.  Doing that forced it to somehow open a cmd prompt with the powershell command.  But it didn't show anything after that, and there is still no file output

Comment: It would be far better to try to **edit/update** your question with all that, then try to do that in a comment.  It is almost completely unreadable in a comment.